# Connecting 100 DC motors (3V) to a battery or mains

Tags: motor, mains

I'm doing an art project in which I want to connect 100 3V motors together to all spin at the same time. I have used junction boxes before for lights and I'm wondering if these could be connected to the mains or even a car battery if mains is not possible?

If I cannot connect 100 then is there a maximum number that I could connect?

Thanks for your advice

Luke

[image: Image of actual motor]

Comment: What are motor specs?

Comment: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/3V-D-C-Miniature-Reversible-Model-Electric-Motor-2mm-Shaft-1-5V-4-5V-/120822293711?hash=item1c2191e4cf

Comment: What are the motors driving? Can you measure the operating current?

Comment: You must determine if the motors are adequate to turn the load connected to the shaft and the resulting current. You must connect the motors only to a source that has a voltage that matches the motor voltage rating. Mains voltage is AC, and much higher than 3 V. A car battery is DC, but also has a voltage that is higher than 3 V. You need one or more voltage converters (power supplies) that are suitable to convert mains or car battery voltage to 3 VDC and sufficient current. Car batteries are not designed to be repeatedly discharged and charged. Available current must be adequate.

Comment: Can you group a few of them, say 4 to make series connected groups of 12 V? If the load is very different on them, this is not a good idea. If fairly equal, this would make it easier to use standard power supplies.

Comment: If you really want to do this, either get a number of high current 3.3 volt switch mode power supplies, or more realistically see if you can find somewhat higher voltage motors so that you can use more readily available 5 volt supplies.  Do beware that the motors will *not* spin at the same speed but will show variation due to manufacturing tolerances.

Comment: First, a big question. Do you require that the motors spin independently (not mechanically linked) but at exactly the same speed? If so, you're out of luck with these motors.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the specs of your motor:-

[3V Rated D.C. Miniature Reversible Model Motor, 2mm Shaft, 1.5V to 4.5V](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/3V-D-C-Miniature-Reversible-Model-Electric-Motor-2mm-Shaft-1-5V-4-5V-/120822293711?hash=item1c2191e4cf)

```
No Load Start Voltage         0.6V     
Rated voltage                 3.0V
No load current               0.34A
No load speed                 16400 rpm nominal
Rated load                    8 g.cm
Rated load current            1.07A
Rated load speed              13100 rpm nominal
Length excluding shaft        25mm
Diameter                      20mm
Width across flats            15.1mm
Shaft length                  9.4mm
Shaft diameter                2 mm
Weight                        17g
Magnet Type                   Ferrite
```

We can calculate the internal resistance from the change in rpm and current between no-load and rated load, (3.0 V - (3.0 V * 13100 rpm / 16400 rpm)) / (1.07 A - 0.34 A) = 0.83 Ω. Then the stall current is 3.0 V / 0.83 Ω = ~3.6 A.

Depending on mechanical load the operating current should be somewhere between 0.34 A and 1.07 A. If we assume an operating current of 0.7 A then to power 100 motors simultaneously your 3 V power supply would have to deliver 70 A continuous and up to 360 A peak (perhaps a bit less due to resistance of the wires going to the motors).

To use a car battery you need a way to reduce the voltage from 12 V to 3 V. This could be done with small DC/DC 'buck' converters such as [this](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/5-pcs-Ultra-Small-DC-DC-Step-Down-3A-Adjustable-Buck-Converter-Replace-LM2596/253063733425?hash=item3aebc620b1:g:XNEAAOSwrk5ZeAJD). As the converter 'transforms' the voltage down it increases current output by the same ratio (less ~10% conversion loss), so a motor current of 0.7 A would only draw ~0.2 A from the battery.

If the DC/DC converter is mounted on or close to the motor then the power supply wiring can be thinner because it doesn't have to carry as much current. However the converter draws current in pulses, so you should then add a large electrolytic capacitor (eg. 220uF) across the converter input to eliminate voltage spikes caused by the wiring inductance.

Using DC/DC converters the 12 V car battery would have to supply 0.2 A * 100 = 20 A, which is roughly equivalent to four 55 W headlights. Whilst it should be able to do it, the battery would not last long at this current because car batteries are not designed for continuous drain at high current.

However high current 12 V power supplies are readily available, so something like [this](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/AC-To-DC-12V-40A-480W-Regulated-Switch-Power-Supply-Adapter-for-LED-Strip-Light/203076518573?hash=item2f484dc2ad:g:NzgAAOSw-NhfNgMH) would be a better solution if mains power is available. Alternatively you could use several smaller power supplies each powering one bank of motors, eg. four 12 V  10 A supplies powering 25 motors each. Either way the power supply should be rated for higher current for cooler running and so it doesn't shut down during the higher motor startup current.

Answer (score -2):

If you rectify an AC supply to get a DC supply then you could run a large number of DC motors in series, but the motors aren’t designed to deal with large voltages safely, so the whole contraption wouldn’t be safe to handle.  Depending on the mechanical setup you might find that some motors might stall and others be exposed to an excessive voltage.  In general it’s not a good idea.

Comment: Series connection of DC motors shouldn't be considered an option for reasons that you have outlined.